# Access 2000 reporting functionality substitute

Tags: reporting-services, ms-access-2000

Here in my job, we use Access 2000 as our only report deployment tool, and as many of you know, Access 2000 has some limitations, like not supporting OOP.

My question is:

What is the better replacement for it, Crystal Reports, Active Reports or SQL Server Reporting Services ? If you guys have any better idea, I would be happy to know it.

Comment: Really depends on what your reporting requirements and limitations are, any further details?

Comment: In acess 2000 you can bring the code funcionality to reporting, this is what we need, sou you can edit with functions, events and so on. Sry for my english, i guess it's not so good, i'am from brazil. Resuming, we need something similar we have in acess with Object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been searching and finally found the answer. First of all there are a lot of tools capable of this task, examples: Crystal Reports with RAS(Report application server, a crystal reports solution for building dynamic reports) API for .NET; You can do with xml and SSRS, first you generate a xml file with the information and then use the rdlc to display it. You can use Xtrareports a devexpress team solution. You with c# code create and manage your reports. This is it.